# Download all files of category from SharePoint library?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to download all the files from a SharePoint library that have the same metadata flag?  Ie I have a list that has a custom column "Document type" which is a choice with n values.  Is it possible to download (or copy) only those documents with a value of "Design documents"?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in functionality that supports this that I am aware of.  However, a SharePoint developer could code something that would accomplish this.